# Is it generally taken that the thesis of Kant's first antinomy fails?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics, kant

Kant presented four antinomies, each presented as a pair of thesis & antithesis.

The first says that the world does have a beginning in time, he argues by contradiction:

> If we assume that the world has no beginning in time, then upto every given
>   moment an eternity has elapsed, and there has passed away in the world an
>   infinite series of successive states of things. Now the infinity of a series consists in the fact that it can never be completed through successive synthesis. It thus follows that it is impossible for an infinite world-series to have passed away, and that a beginning of the world is therefore a necessary condition of the world' s existence.

Priest, in his book [*Beyond the Limits of Thought*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/703718) demolishes his argument by appealing to set theory and stating that Kant's appeal to Aristotle's assertion that completed infinities do not exist doesn't hold.

As far as I see, Priest's argument doesn't hold:

Set theory does have infinities, but I'd argue this simply marks out a new iteration towards the infinite which doesn't have a completion. More importantly, set theory is conceptual, and time is a physical notion. One needs to think about the infinite past in a *physical* way - and this is exactly what Kant is doing by saying "[T]here has passed away in the world [...]". I can't see how it is possible to assert that time past can be infinite when we consider that time must *pass*. We could have, indeed an infinite number of worlds before us, with *their own* notion of time - but in this world with its *own* notion of time - time past must be finite.

Of course, with the Standard Model it is taken that time does have a beginning.

Is there a better argument as to why it must fail? Or is Priest simply presenting the standard arguments? Or is the failure of this thesis actually beside the point - seeing that Kant is working at the limits of what we can know?

Comment: Since I don't understand what "successive synthesis" means, it's just looks like Kant boldly asserts:"Infinite series don't exist because they don't." So please, enlighten me on "successive synthesis". Second, you can't imagine an infinite time. Well, you're limited and so am I, that doesn't mean that infinite series don't exist, whether conceptually or physically.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: If an infinite time existed in the past then it would take an infinite amount of time to reach now. That seems contradictory to me. Successive synthesis looks obvious to me - wheres your problem with it?

Comment: If an infinite amount of integers exist before zero, it would take an infinite amount to reach zero. So what? Zero exists. I don't see any contradiction. Just lack of imagination.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: No, not particularly. You're not thinking physically - but mathematically. Time is a physical notion, not a mathematical one. Its modelled mathematically, so one has to be careful. When the mathematicians at Princeton Uni got excited about the Banach-Tarski paradox, Feynman asked them cooly how it would apply to the Sun - and as they began to explain, he said - well that assumption won't *work*. This doesn't mean that the Banach-Tarski paradox isn't interesting - it is. Similarly integers have no *physical notion of time*, they exist timelessly.

Comment: I know that story. So what? That does not rule out the possibility that the universe has always been. The only problem with the notion is that it is untestable scientifically, so there's no point in advancing it while it might very well be true. But it is certainly not valid to rule it out because we don't like it or can't wrap our minds around it.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: In a timeless platonic realm, if you're inclined that way.

Comment: But that's not my point. My point is: if you're gonna assert the universe can not be infinitely old because it can't. Then, I'm intitled to laugh your proposition away. What is advanced without proof/evidence can be discarded without proof/evidence.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Kant doesn't rule it out. His thesis is that there is a beginning to time. His anti-thesis is that there isn't. He offers I think good arguments for both.

Comment: But his arguments are unconvincing, right?

Comment: @Raskalnikov: Well, that is what I'm *asking*. I think his arguments have been taken apart - and I think that some of those arguments are shaky. For example the continuum is made up of points (which had been advanced by Priest as grounds for dismissing another one of his antinomies) - when recent arguments have been made its the topology that matters and not points. So you can have a pointless line. So that argument by Priest doesn't stand. It's obvious to me that Priest is thinking wholly mathematically and sometimes not physically enough.

Comment: And I'm saying Kant's argument is bad because his "successive synthesis" argument is bad.

Comment: @raskolnikov: well, apart from mocking/sneering - you're not exactly offering any arguments of your own either.

Comment: It would help though if you included an explanation of what "successive synthesis" is.

Comment: @MoziburUllah As an aside: Assuming you have read it, would you recommend Priest's _Beyond the Limits of Thought_?

Comment: @Gugg: Yes, I think it's written well, and he looks broadly. He is sometimes too quick to dismiss certain arguments by appealing to mathematics without think things through - like the example I mentioned above the continuum and the one in the question.

Comment: I find Priest to be muddled on most issues including this one. I don't know if this particular argument of Kant's works but there are plenty of others. Hence most physicists favour some sort of ex nihilo creation. A crucial issue would be that although an eternal universe in time makes no sense,. nor does the idea that time had a beginning. This antimony can only be solved by adopting the view of time and space endorsed by the Perennial philosophy, for which it would be incorrect to say that time does or does-not have a beginning, and that this would be why both ideas do not work. .  .

Comment: PS. This is such a crucial issue that it deserves our full attention. Most people see that the idea that time had a beginning is absurd, and also see the idea that it didn't as absurd. They walk away scratching their head. But this is important data from which we cannot walk away. it suggests that our idea of time is all wrong. If we ignore antinomies we might as well ignore metaphysics since understanding them is the whole task. It can be done but as Russell states very clearly, not within the dualism that besets the Western tradition of thought.   .

Comment: @PeterJ: As a physicist, I tend to think that real things do not show any aspect of the infinite; given that, it seems that time must have had a beginning. Though of course this does not give any indication how far i the past this is.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - Okay, but it doesn't seem to many people that time must have had a beginning. (When did it start?) But yes, if you think it makes sense that it had a beginning then my comment is not relevant for you.

Comment: @PeterJ: I appreciate that there are differences of opinion, but I thought that the scientific consensus was that time began at the Big Bang?

Answer (score 2):

Priest does not demolish Kant. Priest is wrong.

First, even Cantor has stated that time never can be actually infinite: "[...] for instance, the time elapsed since the beginning of the world, which, measured in some time-unit, for instance a year, is finite in every moment, but always growing beyond all finite limits, without ever becoming really infinitely large." [G. Cantor, letter to I. Jeiler (13 Oct 1895)]

And he offered to prove that the elapsed time is never infinite: "I do not only maintain with all Christian philosophers the temporal beginning of the creation, I also claim like you that this truth can be proven by rational reasons. [...] The foundation of actually infinitely great or, as I call them, transfinite numbers does not entail that we have to refrain from rational proofs of the beginning of the world." [G. Cantor, letter to J. Hontheim (21 Dec 1893)]

Second, if something infinite could be completed, then the sequence 1, 2, 3, ... would be the first candidate. But then we would have to accept that Scrooge McDuck who earns 10 enumerated dollars per day and spends one dollar, can become bankrupt in the set-theoretic limit, i.e., in the case of completed infinity. This is such a ridiculous result that we have good reason to consider set theory with its actual infinite as demolished. All people whom I know have agreed  when I told them this story.

By the way the formalism of limits in set theory can be found here:
https://www.hs-augsburg.de/~mueckenh/Transfinity/Transfinity/pdf, p. 55f.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of Kant, arguing against the infinity of time, contains an error, nobody has pointed out.

The general intuition that an accumulation of an infinite amount of 'things' would form an "actual infinity", so an infinity which has been completely absorbed, counted, etc., would be a contradiction, is of course correct. But as applied to time, the logical conclusion would be that *just because that would be a contradiction*, infinity of time is an endless/beginingless proces, unfolding in time.

The critical point then is that the infinite moments of time of the past, and the infinite moments in the future do not exist "at the same time", only the motion of the ever ongoing "now"...

As further demonstration to this, imagine the timeline without begin or end. Now place anywhere on the timeline two points, and measure the distance. The point is then, that wherever you place these two points, the distance between them is always strictly **finite**.
Infinity then (since the timeline *is* infinite, it contains infinitely many points) is composed of only finite. 
Every measure of time on an infinite timeline is still a finite duration. Hence the *actual infinite* does not occur...

Answer (score -2):

Kants arguments use a model of time that we no longer accept in our physical universe. Including time in the arguments adds considerable heat but no light. I will endeavour to use time free arguments where possible.

**Thesis.**

- That the universe cannot be infinite.

He states that there cannot be an infinite series of things. But there can be and there are. There are an uncountable infinite number of reals between 0 and 1.

He mistakes the way we model things with what they are. We model a table top as a surface with an infinite number of points, but that does not mean that the table top has infinite area, or is an infinite object. The points on the surface don't actually exist as physical objects. They are a description of a finite thing using infinities.

Then he argues that open infinities such as zero to plus and minus infinity, but these are no larger than the closed infinities, both being uncountable. We can map infinity .. 1 to 0..1 using 1/x.

**Antithesis**

- That the universe must be finite.

He starts by assuming that the spatial universe is infinite and asks why is only a finite part of the universe occupied. Then part is unocupied and part is occupied without any distinguishing reason why this is so.

Then take a mandelbrot set as a 2D universe. Part is occupied. Part is empty, and this case the rule is based on number. If I transform the mandelbrot positions by 1/x I get my emptiness on the outside.
 U(x, y) = Mandelbrot((1/x)+i(1/y)

So what is the distinguishing condition? The relationship of the complex number to the origin. Would Kant argue that there should be no origin? I don't see that stated, and even he did that would only positional self similarity. So I create a self similar patterning of the universe with empty pieces.

Or is he actually arguing cause and effect? That is a completely different argument.

Comment: One particular problem is not even touched by this answer: The consideration of what *things*, *world*, and *synthesis* means *for Kant*. He speaks of objects of possible experience, and even though we know *concepts* of infinity, there is no *intuition from sensibility*, and therefore no *experience* of infinity in his sense. In other words, there is only abstract infinity, but we cannot really grasp it, hence we don't have such things (sic!) as 'infinite series of *things*' and the *sum if all things*, world, can't be infinite if it shall be a concept with reality *for us*, as well.

Comment: @ Philip Klöcking A line has an infinite number of points on it,.Infinities arise from a mathematical description of finite objects. They are not infinities of the world. We deal with them by measure theory. Kants model is not the modern one. We are an intelligence that arose from the playing out of the rules of the universe. We interpret the information from our senses.and construct the simplest model of that data from Occam's Razor. If abstract infinities arise in modelling, that is not an issue.

Comment: My point is: You presuppose a metaphysical position of (a particular kind of) scientific realism Kant does not agree with. Even among scientific realists the ontological status of infinities is subject of discussions. So there are two problems you do not address. Instead, you just assert things that are far from being unproblematic without bothering to support this with sources. The question whether Kant's argument fails depends on metaphysical positions.

Comment: Hmmm. OK. Kant doesn't agree that we are monkeys that evolved too large brains? Kant doesn't agree that we extract information from our senses, by building models that predict and compress the data? Kant doesn't agree that an infinity is a limit? A number as large as we need it to be. Mea Culpa. I thought that was a given. No wonder I see his argument as totally wonky.

Comment: Firstly, it is apes, not monkeys. Secondly, Kant agrees on much more than you seem to understand, just not on the naive application of abstract concepts and labelling it as knowledge about some *thing*. This is what his critical philosophy is all about. Thirdly, no need for sarcasm, I am just pointing out that criticising Kant without understanding his position or critical reflection on one's own metaphysical position (which is far less 'given' than you think imho) is problematic. Even more so if it is not supported by references.

Comment: Reading through the answer, you don't seem to be particularly up to speed on how Kant's philosophy works. In your first sentence you state: `Kants arguments use a model of time that we no longer accept in our physical universe` but there's several problems here. Kant's account of time is not a description of the physical universe but rather a description of what he takes to be our necessary epistemological equipment (it's an open question among Kant scholars whether he's committing to an ontology here or an ontological skeptic).

Comment: @ virmaior Time is irrelevant to this argument. So he adds complexity by talking about time. There are at least four dimensions and there could be more. The spaces may or may not be curved. Our universe may be a small part of a larger universe. A universe can have any pattern he wants. Be empty in places, be not empty in others, as influenced by the rules of that universe, and the interactions with others. This changes if you invoke cause and effect, but that is separate, much more interesting argument. For that argument, it is too narrow to think in terms of spatial or time dimensions.